# Fender/mudguard that detaches with front wheel, is there such a thing?

Tags: fenders

I have a Carrera Tanneri Cyclocross Bike [identical to this one](http://www.halfords.com/cycling/bikes/road-bikes/carrera-tanneri-limited-edition-cyclocross-bike-2015-black) with 700 x 35c wheels.

[image]

I got some mudguards with it that were a bit too wide so I changed them for some generic plastic ones that fitted in between the forks and then hung freely following the curve of the tyre.

The problem I have is that when I store the bike in the car, the front wheel has to come off leaving the mudguard sticking out. The heat inside the car was sufficient to deform the plastic mudguard so much that it fouled the tyre and had to be chucked away.

Is there such a thing as a mudguard that detaches with front wheel?

Comment: If you don't mind the look, MTB style ones often do. I have a  Topeaks that easily unclip. Depending how much protection you want - one that attaches to the down tube might be better, again have a look at what  MTB's use.

Comment: I did have a look at some MTB but like you say, they do look a bit strange with this frame and they are much wider than the tyres. I'll look into ones that attach to the downtube. Mine is quite thick vertically but narrow horizontally and the mountings on the ones in my local shop were the wrong shape.

Comment: One solution might be to cut the front part of the mudguard off at the fork crown, and use the front half of a detachable mudguard there. I've obtained a few millimetres extra tyre size by doing that on my commuting bike (the mudguard doesn't run under the fork, one section stops each side)

Comment: How hot is your car?!  Were they particularly cheap MTB mudguards?   They tend to be quite bendy to allow for movement. You might be better off with some close-fitting 700 mudguards with a support strut, or maybe carry the bike outside the car ?

Comment: There is a splash guard that attaches to the down tube.  Not as effective as a front fender, but it's not in the way when you remove the wheel.

Comment: And note that if it gets warm enough in the car to deform a plastic fender then it's warm enough to cook the lubrication out of the bearings.

Comment: If temperature-resistance is your primary problem, you can consider narrow, city aluminium fenders. I guess that your fenders deformed not because of temperature of your bike interior (your car plastic interior did not deformed, I suppose), but because it was dark/black, exposed on direct sun, absorbed much energy and because of poor quality become plastic. You can consider some bright-coloured stuff.

Comment: Finally, you can replace regular screw with quick-release and make any single-point mounted fender as easy-detachable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys, my car is a large SUV type vehicle. I live in the UK and the car has tinted windows so the interior temperature isn't crazy hot but warm enough in the summer. When the bike was laying on its side the back without the front wheel for support the mudguard will have been pressing against the floor or something in the interior causing it to warp and deform. I'll keep looking then maybe invent something if I can't find anything suitable :D